Wordpress Ajax and Plugins
I think I'm nearly there with this, but can't get the final pieces despite hours of research and trial and error. I have a form on a page in Wordpress, and I want users to be able to run database queries based on their form input, then display the results below. So far as I'm aware, the "best" method of doing this is through Ajax.
Where I'm at: I've written a simple Wordpress plugin comprising of the main php file (systembuilder.php, in the default plugins folder):
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: System Builder

**/



function builder_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'builder-js', plugins_url( '/js/systembuilder.js', __FILE__ ));
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_mriSearch', 'mriSearch' );   
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mriSearch', 'mriSearch' );  


function mriSearch() {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = $_POST['query'];

    $result = "Running mriSearch";
    #$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($query, $inDate, $inMRILow, $inMRIHi) );
    echo json_encode($result, true);
    
    die();
}

and a Javascript file (systembuilder.js, in a folder named js under the plugin):
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#MRISearchForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var form = $(this);
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: actionUrl,
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                // Process with the response data
                $('#search_results').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

And a form on a Wordpress page:
<form type="post" action="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" role="form" id="MRISearchForm">
    <p style="font-size: 16pt;">Date: <input style="font-size: 16pt;" type="date" name="inDate" width="200" height="32"></p>
    <p style="font-size: 16pt;">Minimum MRI: <input style="font-size: 16pt;" type="number" name="inMRILow" value="70" min="0" max="100" width="200" height="32"></p>
    <p style="font-size: 16pt;">Maximum MRI: <input style="font-size: 16pt;" type="number" name="inMRIHi" value="100"  min="0" max="100" width="200" height="32"></p>
 
    
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mriSearch"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" style="font-size: 18pt;">
    <input type="reset" style="font-size: 18pt;">
</form> 
<div id="search_results"></div>

I haven't written any of the database query, etc. yet, just want to get this working first.
Submitting the form gives me a blank page with "Running mriSearch". I can't seem to get the scripts to update the "search_results" div, rather than just a blank page (url is ....com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?inDate=&inMRILow=70&inMRIHi=100&action=mriSearch&submit=Search).
I have tried to submit the form to my plugin php, I've tried it with the action empty, I've tried a million and one different things, and I'm sure that it's something pretty simple.

it seems like the ajax call is not been made at all, can you confirm few things

is the JS file loaded
is the on submit method getting triggered, what do you see if you console log 'this' inside the onsubmit method


Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. Turns out that no, the JS file wasn't being loaded, as it had it inside a function which was never called (dumb). I also had to enqueue jQuery in PHP:
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script( 'builder-js', plugins_url( 'js/systembuilder.js', FILE ));
And one more minor edit to the JS function:
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

You should use action:'mriSearch'  in data
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#MRISearchForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var form = $(this);
        var actionUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";

        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: actionUrl,
            data: {
                action:'mriSearch', 
                postData: : form.serialize()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                // Process with the response data
                $('#search_results').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});


Tried this, but it still gave me the same response as previously
